# NoMethodError but did 'require_relative'

Tags: ruby

I did the 'requir_relative' but still got the NoMethodError.

There are 2 ruby files, under 'run.rb' I have this

```
class Run
  def separate(data)
    hash_block = []
    (0...data.count).each do |i|
      f = data[i].split('|')
      hash_block[i] = Hashing.new(f[0].to_i, f[1], f[2], f[3], f[4])
    end
    hash_block
  end
end
```

and then in the main file, I did these:

```
require_relative 'run'

...some codes...

to_separate = IO.readlines(ARGV[0])
separated = separate(to_separate)

...some codes...
```

but I still get this:

```
in `block in <main>': undefined method `separate' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

If I cut the method and paste it in the main file it will work as expected but that is something I wanted to avoid.

Comment: what is the name of the file with the `class Run` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to call the method within the class Run you have to instantiate it. Since is an instance method. The way your calling the class is giving you the error `undefined` because it can not find it with in the scope of your current file

```
run_instance = Run.new 
to_separate = IO.readlines(ARGV[0])
sperated = run_instance.separate(to_separate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You required the file, but in that file you have a class definition. `separate` is inside that class (and that's an instance method), so you need an object to call the method on.

```
separated = Run.new.separate(to_separate)
```